# Hacer validaciones en una funcion con React/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un problema. Y es que tengo una función que agrega superhéroes que se ejecuta cuando hago un click y se almacena en equipoS.

El problema es que cuando el personaje con el id es duplicado se agrega igual y después cambia el valor del estado 'controlador'.

Lo que se supone quiero que haga es que itere los elementos del arreglo y valide si el id de los elementos del arreglo coinciden con el id que le paso como 'props'.

En caso de que haya un id que coincida con el de los arreglos, lance la alerta de 'El personaje ya fue agregado al grupo'. Caso contrario que ejecute la alerta 'Se agrego el personaje al grupo'

```js
const [controlador, setcontrolador] = useState(false)
const equipoS = [spiderMan,Venom,Ironman]

    const agregarHeroe = (props) => {

        for (let index = 0; index < equipoS.length; index++) {
            if(props.id === equipoS[index].id){
              setcontrolador(true)
              alert('El personaje ya fue agregado al grupo')
              }
        }

        if (equipoS.length >= 0 && equipoS.length < 6 && !controlador) {
            equipoSuperheroe(el)
            alert('Se agrego el personaje al grupo')
        }
        if (equipoS.length === 6) alert('Se a alcanzado la capacidad maxima del equipo')

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la ejecución entra en el `if` del bucle, deberás detener la ejecución del mismo:

```
for (let index = 0; index < equipoS.length; index++) {
    if(props.id === equipoS[index].id){
        setcontrolador(true);
        alert('El personaje ya fue agregado al grupo');
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias bro, era eso <3